# winrt c++ tasks queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-runtime

I need make a task queue in c++/cx but due to my poor experience i dont know how.
The purpose is:
 - creating the task in some thread with lambda ("task1 = [] () {}")
 - then add this task to task queue, task queue executing in other thread
 - when task expecting it queue, it doesnt execute
 - tasks executing only after previously executed task

As i got, when you use auto a = concurrency::create_task(lambda) it start immediately. Delayed start of such task need an pointer to previous task, but i cant get it as my tasks generated in separate threads.

So could anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like proper using of `std::task_group` can solve my problem.
Also `std::task_handle` dont execute on creation so using it may solve my problem too, but it needs its own queue.